# EF ChangeTracker.Entries().Where not recognized

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Using VS2010 SP1 MVC4 and EF6.  I have this pretty generic code.  It's meant to grab the DateCreated and DateModified properties and populate them on every save.

```
foreach (var history in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(e => e.Entity is IModificationHistory && (e.State == EntityState.Added ||
      e.State == EntityState.Modified))
    .Select(e => e.Entity as IModificationHistory))
{
    history.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
    if (history.DateCreated == DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        history.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
int result = base.SaveChanges();
```

I'm getting an error on the `.Where`. When I put a `.` after `Entries()` the intellisense doesn't give an option for `Where`, just the 5 standard `GetType`, etc. If I remove the where clause, then the .Select shows an error.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Are you missing a `using System.Linq` directive?

Comment: Yes, it's the using. Note that you should rather use `this.ChangeTracker.Entries<IModificationHistory >()`.

Answer (score 1):

Will was correct - I didn't have the using statement.  Very embarrassing.  Thank you.

Comment: Ran into same issue.  Perfect catch @Will Ray.  Got to know new thing, VS intelligence don't work for extension method.  Thanks Gert Arnold for suggesting alternative method to fetch IModificationHistory objects out of ChangeTracker without using .Where()